# Как опустить кнопку вниз блока?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Мне необходимо опустить кнопку вниз, чтобы она всегда была с отступом от низа в 100px. У меня не получается это сделать, пробовал через position:absolute; не получается. Делать через margin-top не хочу тк. с изменением размера экрана кнопка будет сьезжать. Помогите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
header {
 background: url(../img/background-image.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

.header{
 padding-top:50px;
}
.logo{
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'BIG JOHN';
 letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}
.logo:hover{
 cursor: pointer; 
}
.menu a{
 margin-left: 7px;
 font-size: 16px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 padding: 7px 9px;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu a:hover{
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 100px;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s ease;
}
.title h1{
 margin-top:35%;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.title p{

 padding-top: 30px;
 color:#fff;
}
.scroll {
 
}
.scroll img{
 display: block;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.scroll img:hover{
 transition: 0.5s ease;
 transform: scale(1.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="section">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
     <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2 logo">BOUNCY</div>
     <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 offset-3 col-7  menu text-right">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Team</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6  offset-lg-3 col-12 ">
      <div class="text-center title">
       <h1>We Are Code Cafe</h1>
       <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-2 offset-5 text-center scroll">
      <img class="flowing-scroll" href="#this-is" src="img/scroll.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй еще раз absolute, только убери ее из `<div class="row">` просто в контейнере помести

Comment: cпасибо, помогло, но теперь не могу выровнять по центру. Задаю display: block; margin:0 auto; а оно не выравнивается

Comment: при абсолюте margin auto не работает! сделай так:
``` left: 50%;
margin-left: -20px; /* половина ширины твоей стрелки */ ```